# Can't find an element in the browser

Tags: java, object, selenium, automated-tests

I'm building an automation project using Selenium, Java, Cucumber..

I have 3 different classes at this time running the automation code
- Container Class: storing all the WebElements as single methods
- View Class: where all the logic hapens. exp: Performing clicks to the Webelement stored in the container class.
-Steps Class: Where I assert or verify the different pieces of a scenario

My problem is I'm not finding the webelements in the webside when I call the container methods from my view class...

I know the path are OK because if I build the entire scenario in the step class all WebElements are located without issues

I know the view class is excuting the container class because I set a prinln in the container method and is showing up every time the view class attempt to find the WebElement.

**Container Class**

```
 package com.automation.automation.prototype.containers;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class loginContainer {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public loginContainer(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;

    }

    public WebElement loginEmail(){

        //xpath that is not beign located
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']"));

    }
}
```

**View Class**

```
package com.automation.automation.prototype.views;
import com.automation.automation.prototype.containers.loginContainer;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.automation.automation.prototype.containers.loginContainer;

public class loginView {

private static loginContainer login;


    public loginView(WebDriver driver) {

        login = new loginContainer(driver);
        }

    public boolean insertEmail( String email) throws InterruptedException{

        boolean valid = false; 
        int flag = 0;
        int attemps = 0; 

        do{
            attemps++;

            try{
                login.loginEmail().click();
                login.loginEmail().sendKeys(email);

                System.out.println("Element Found!: "+attemps);
            valid = true;
            flag = 1;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Element Searching: "+attemps);
            }
    }while (attemps <20 && flag ==0);
            return valid;}
}
```

**Step Class**

```
 package com.automation.automation.prototype;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

    import com.automation.automation.prototype.containers.URLs;
    import com.automation.automation.prototype.containers.loginContainer;
    import com.automation.automation.prototype.views.loginView;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

    public class steps {

        private  WebDriver driver;
        private static URLs URL;

        private static loginView LoginView2;
        //private static loginContainer LoginContainerstep;


        public steps(){

            URL = new URLs(driver);
            //LoginContainerstep = new loginContainer(driver);
            LoginView2 = new loginView(driver);

        }
        @Given(value = "^Launch$")
        public void login() throws Throwable{

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.get(URL.fbURL);

            System.out.println(URL.fbURL);

        }

            @Then(value = "^insertCredentials (.*)$")
            public void insertCredentials_and_and(String email) throws InterruptedException{

                assertTrue("ELEMENT IS NOT SHOWING UP", LoginView2.insertEmail(email));

                }
```

Comment: what exception you are facing. provide that

Comment: you should really try to minimize the code to just reproduce the failure + provide an exception

Comment: I'm really curious why you are creating `LoginView2 = new loginView(driver) `in constructor but you create the `driver = new FirefoxDriver()` in Given method. You should create the driver before you call it.

Comment: provide exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize the code. Better to make a common class where you can put login, setup and teardown function, and use the main class (containing main logics and calling the function required from common). Secondly, try to take care for access modifiers. Thirdly, try to check the different types XPATH can be defined. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use this : instead of a retry 

public WebElement findElementSafe(By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
        try {
            return findElement(selector, timeOutInSeconds);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

public WebElement findElement(By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));
        return findElement(driver, selector);
    }


public void waitForElementToAppear(By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeOutInSeconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
    }

    public void waitForElementToDisappear(By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeOutInSeconds);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
    }
```